# Pandas - rolling codes with dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame which contains an ID, Code and Date. For certain codes I would like to fill subsequent appearances of the ID, based on the date, with a determined set of missing codes. I would also like to know the first appearance of the code against the respective ID.

Example as follows, NB: missing codes are A and B (only codes A and B carry over):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1], 'date': ['2017-03-22', '2017-03-21',     '2017-03-23', '2017-03-24', '2017-03-28', '2017-03-28'], 'Code': ['A, C', 'A', 'B, C', 'E, D', 'A', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# only A and B codes carry over
df
```

The target dataframe would ideally look as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1], 'date': ['2017-03-22', '2017-03-21', '2017-03-24', '2017-03-22', '2017-03-28', '2017-03-28'], 'Code': ['A, C', 'A', 'B, C', 'E, D', 'A', 'C'], 'Missing_code': ['', '', 'A', 'A', '', 'A, B'], 'First_code_date': ['', '', '2017-03-22', '2017-03-21', '', '2017-03-23, 2017-03-24']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Note I am not fussy on how the 'First_code_date' looks providing it is dynamic as the code length may increase or decrease.

If the example is not clear please let me know and I will adjust.

Thank you for help.

Comment: what is the output you require?

Comment: The target data frame - the ‘missing_code’ series and the ‘first_code_date’ series.

Comment: The condition to select the output is not clear with the example given. Please rephrase the condition and with examples,